# Powershell New-SmbMapping drives only accessible from Powershell and not windows

Tags: sql-server, powershell, smb

I'm new to SMB 3.0 and I'm trying to mount a drive in Server 2012.  I have a SMB 3.0 share on another server.  I've used the new-smbmapping powershell command to mount an L drive.  This L Drive can be seen in Powershell and accessed in powershell.  However nothing outside of powershell can see this drive.   The documentation I have found says this replaces the net-use.

Essentially I am trying to get the OS to see the smb 3.0 share and map it to a drive letter.   To be more specific I am trying to get SQL Server to do a backup to a network share using a specific network interface adapter (Mellanox)  In Windows Explorer I can easily use \server\share name and it goes across the correct interface... but if I specify the same thing in the backup job it doesn't use the right interface.

Answer (score 3):

If it's anything like `New-PSDrive`, you will need to add the `-Persistent`  option. Without `-Persistent`, it is just a powershell path alias, and not a system mapping.

Comment: That was my first guess, but same behaviour if `-Persistent $true` is present or not. Using this command with explorer exhibits very unusual behaviour.